# Handle Adaptive Card button inside LuisIntent method

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding, adaptive-cards

I am developing a bot using MS Bot Framework and LUIS and there are a lot of Adaptive Cards with buttons in my conversation flow. I need a way to handle this flow with buttons (Action.Submit buttons to be precise).

I first tried:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
{
   if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
   {
       if (activity.Text != null & activity.Value == null)
       {
          await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new RootLuisDialog());
       }
       else if (activity.Text == null & activity.Value != null)
       {
         await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new ButtonHandler());
       }
   }
   else
   {
       this.HandleSystemMessage(activity);
   }

   var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
   return response;
}
```

Because when the button on an Adaptive Card is clicked `activity.Value` contains the properties of the Action.Submit button.

The idea was to be able to separate the button controllers and the intent controller which is `RootLuisDialog()`. But it did not work, I don't know why: With this code, always the `RootLuisDialog()` exit is taken. In other words, the dialog stays inside `RootLuisDialog()`

Second idea was to use `None` Luis Intent like so:

```
    [LuisIntent("")]
    [LuisIntent("None")]
    public async Task None(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        var act = context.Activity as IMessageActivity;
        string message = String.Empty;
        if (act.Text != null & act.Value == null)
        {
            message = $"Sorry, I did not understand '{act.Text}'. Type 'help' if you need assistance.";
        }
        else if (act.Text == null & act.Value != null)
        {
            Button btn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Button>(act.Value.ToString());
            message = $"You clicked on {btn.Type}";
        }
        await context.PostAsync(message);

        context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);
    }
```

While this works, it does not look right to be pushing button code under `None` intent.

I also tried `context.Wait(buttonHandler)` where the `buttonHandler` is an async function to handle the button press but then I got this error message:

```
   "exceptionMessage": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
   "exceptionType": "System.NullReferenceException",
```

I am sure what I am trying to achieve has already a good answer but this being my first C# project/task, I need help to get this sorted.
Many thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that a better design if you want to separate the handling of the buttons from the `LUIS` intents, could be having a RootDialog that does 3 things:

1. Inspect the incoming activity
2. If `activity.Value` is null, then FWD the activity to LuisDialog (using `context.Forward`. Assuming that you want to inspect all the messages for 1), then you will have to "end" the LUIS dialog after you perform your logic with `context.Done` (instead of doing `context.Wait(...)`)
3. If `activity.Value` is not null, then you can process the message in the RootDialog and end with a `context.Wait(...)`;